# Implement connection pooling with Python for connecting to SQL Server on Windows

Tags: python, sql-server, windows, database-connection

I am writing a Python script that will read data from a SQL Server database. For this I have used pyodbc to connect to SQL Server on Windows (my driver is ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server).

My script works fine, but I need to use a **connection pool** instead of a single connection to manage resources more effectively. However the documentation for pyodbc only mentions pooling without providing examples of how connection pooling can be implemented. Any ideas of how this can be done using Python while connecting to an SQL Server? I only found solutions for PostgreSQL that use psycopg2, but this does not work for me obviously.

At the moment my code looks like this (please disregard the missing indentation which happened when copying the file from my IDE):

```
def get_limited_rows(size):
try:
    server = 'here-is-IP-address-of-servier'
    database = 'here-is-my-db-name'
    username = 'here-is-my-username'
    password = 'here-is-my-password'
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print('Connected to database')

    select_query = 'select APPN, APPD from MAIN'
    cursor.execute(select_query)
    while True:
        records = cursor.fetchmany(size)
        if not records:
            cursor.close()
            sys.exit("Completed")
        else: 
            for record in records:
                print(record)
            time.sleep(10)
except pyodbc.Error as error:
    print('Error reading data from table', error)
finally:
    if (conn):
        conn.close()
        print('Data base connection closed')
```

Comment: Pooling is automatic, assuming the driver implements it. Just make sure your connections are always closed (use `finally` blocks)

Comment: @Charlieface thanks! from what I see in pyodbc documentation, pooling is indeed enabled by default, I just did not realise how this should actually look in the script. Re your mentioning the closing of connections - you meant the finally block like in the one I used in my code, right? (just making sure I understood your point correctly)

Comment: Yes just make sure you do that every time, otherwise the connection will leak

Comment: The issue is that the `pyodbc.connect` is taking almost 2 seconds is making us think its not using the connection pool. If the connection already exists, why would that take 2 seconds when the query itself takes an additional 300 ms.